# Reverse-engineering Bitcoin to a formal specification

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, protocol, academic-research, specification

Is there any attempt/project to reverse-engineer Bitcoin's reference implementation, not to an informal description (I have found those), rather to a *formal specification*?

I have tried searching but could not find anything using formal methods, but maybe I am just using the wrong keywords.  Thanks for any reference or insight.